# Excel VBA sort not working what is correct syntax for worksheet.range reference

Tags: excel, vba

With the code below I get an error:

**`Run-time error '1004' Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet failed.`**

```
   Dim destLastCol As Integer 'last column in range
   Dim destLastRow As Integer  'last row in range 
   Dim wsCrewDetail As Worksheet '

   Set wsCrewDetail = Worksheets("CrewDetail_M")
   destLastCol =  integer assigned previously
   destLastRow =  integer assigned previously

   With wsCrewDetail.Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(destLastRow, destLastCol)) <== error here
    .Sort Key1:=.Cells(4, 2), Order1:=xlAscending, _
     key2:=.Cells(4, 1), Order2:=xlAscending, _
     key3:=.Cells(4, 3), order3:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
   End With
```

I've searched and viewed many examples trying many variations on setting the `Range` reference and nothing is working.

What is correct reference syntax please?

Edited to add destLastRow =  integer assigned previously and edit to show destLastCol

Comment: you haven't cast any upvotes or accepted any answers.

Comment: Thanks for prompt to look a bit more into the upvotes and accepted.. I have been looking for some UI features to do this .. at the bottom of the comments .. or next to user name .. I've just assumed I am too new to be able to have such input .. I just for first time realized/discerned that the huge (now completely obvious but still frankly a bit unclear...) triangles up and down and checkmark are UI features to give this input).  I checked check mark which I assumed would indicate correct answer.  Clicking the up triangle would I assume move answer up towards 1 but moves it down.

Comment: Any pointers hints tips etc warmly welcomed!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you aren't feeding a row number into `destLastRow` in this line
`With wsCrewDetail.Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(destLastRow, destLastCol))`

Plus, don't use `Integer` variables, use `Long`. They are more efficient and also cater for large numbers.

**suggestions**

- using shorter variables such as `ws` for Worksheet makes it easier to type and read code
- use `Long` rather than `Integer`
- I would normally set a working range (`rng1`) rather than use a longer object starting with the sheet
- dummy `destLastRow` and `destLastCol` values

**sample code**

```
   Dim destLastCol As Long 'last column in range
   Dim destLastRow As Long  'last row in range
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim rng1 As Range

   Set ws = Worksheets("CrewDetail_M")
   destLastCol = 6
   destLastRow = 10

   Set rng1 = ws.Range(ws.Cells(4, 1), ws.Cells(destLastRow, destLastCol))
   With rng1
    .Sort Key1:=.Cells(4, 2), Order1:=xlAscending, _
     key2:=.Cells(4, 1), Order2:=xlAscending, _
     key3:=.Cells(4, 3), order3:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
   End With
```

Comment: Ahh, the "ws.Cells" syntax was the missing piece.  Thanks a lot.  I swear I did not see this syntax in scores of Google searches.  I do exhaustive searches and iterations before asking.  I hear you on other suggestions. In my use case I know I will stay in integer territory, and I like descriptive variable names while developing.  At some point however, I do usually do find/replace to use shorter versions though.

Comment: Also, forgive me, I missed indicating I did have the destLastRow feeding in. Just edited that in.

Comment: @chrisneilsen - good point, I picked this up in the longer edit.